# Dimensions when landscape and portrait orientation changing

Tags: css, media-type

I have media types for landscape and portrait orientations.
All looks like this when the orientation = portrait

[image]

When I turn the phone to the landscape orientation - it applies css stylesheet for the landscape orientation, but dimension is different. Zoom doesn't work.

[image]

That's how the page looks when I load it as a new page. Stylesheet works fine.

[image]

When I change from landscape to portrait orientation - it works also fine.

```
/* For landscape mobile screens */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width:1223px) {
    /* styles */
}
/* For portrait mobile screens */
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
    /*styles*/
}
```

Comment: what is the screen size ?

Comment: Add the code you used please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Landscape @media queries

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

### Portrait @media queries

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```